# I cannot seem to get data into JSON correctly

Tags: php, arrays, class, json

Hello I have spent quite bit of time trying to get my data to look like this in JSON as a sample:

```
var json = {
    "id": "347_0",
    "name": "Nine Inch Nails",
    "children": [{
        "id": "126510_1",
        "name": "Jerome Dillon",
        "data": {
            "band": "Nine Inch Nails",
            "relation": "member of band"
        },
        "children": [{
            "id": "52163_2",
            "name": "Howlin' Maggie",
            "data": {
                "band": "Jerome Dillon",
                "relation": "member of band"
            },
            "children": []
        }, {
            "id": "324134_3",
            "name": "nearLY",
            "data": {
                "band": "Jerome Dillon",
                "relation": "member of band"
            },
            "children": []
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "173871_4",
        "name": "Charlie Clouser",
        "data": {
            "band": "Nine Inch Nails",
            "relation": "member of band"
        },
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "235952_5",
        "name": "James Woolley",
        "data": {
            "band": "Nine Inch Nails",
            "relation": "member of band"
        },
        "children": []
    },
```

I am using the json_encode function and I know how to make the data into JSON I just cannot seem to create anything that will output the above JSON format...For example I use the following code:

```
    foreach($relations as $rel){
        $data[$id]["relationTo"] = $rel["name"];
        $data[$id]["relation"] = $rel["relation"];
        $id = $id + 1;
    }
    $id = 0;
    foreach($relations as $rel){
        $children[$id]["id"] = $id+1;
        $children[$id]["name"] = $rel["sname"];
        $children[$id]["data"] = $data[$id];
        $id = $id + 1;
    }
    $relationsArray["id"] = 0;
    $relationsArray["name"] = $rel["name"];
    $relationsArray["children"] = $children;

    $json_content =  json_encode($relationsArray);
```

And this outputs:

```
"id":0,
"name":"Al",
"children":[
  {
     "id":1,
     "name":"Brandon",
     "data":{
        "relationTo":"Albaraa",
        "relation":"Friend"
     },
     "children":[

     ]
  },
  {
     "id":2,
     "name":"Shen",
     "data":{
        "relationTo":"Albaraa",
        "relation":"Friend"
     },
     "children":[

     ]
  },
  {
     "id":3,
     "name":"Dan",
     "data":{
        "relationTo":"Albaraa",
        "relation":"Professor"
     },
     "children":[

     ]
  },
  {
     "id":4,
     "name":"Bob",
     "data":{
        "relationTo":"Albaraa",
        "relation":"Boss"
     },
     "children":[

     ]
  },
  {
     "id":5,
     "name":"Al",
     "data":{
        "relationTo":"Albaraa",
        "relation":"God Father"
     },
     "children":[

     ]
  },
  {
     "id":6,
     "name":"Albaraa",
     "data":{
        "relationTo":"Shen",
        "relation":"Friend"
     },
     "children":[

     ]
  },
  {
     "id":7,
     "name":"Brandon",
     "data":{
        "relationTo":"Shen",
        "relation":"Friend"
     },
     "children":[

     ]
  },
  {
     "id":8,
     "name":"Dan",
     "data":{
        "relationTo":"Shen",
        "relation":"Professor"
     },
     "children":[

     ]
  },
  {
     "id":9,
     "name":"Albaraa",
     "data":{
        "relationTo":"Al",
        "relation":"God Son"
     },
     "children":[

     ]
  },
  {
     "id":10,
     "name":"Bob",
     "data":{
        "relationTo":"Al",
        "relation":"Best Friends"
     },
     "children":[

     ]
  }
 ]
}
```

and so on...but I am not able to get the children of the children as you see above!

Any help would be amazing thank you!

EDIT:

```
       class Child{
        public $id;
        public $name;
        public $children;
        public $data;

        public function __construct($id, $sname, $data, $rel){
            $this->children = array();
            $this->data = array();
            if ($rel){
                $this->id = $id+1;
                $this->name = $sname;                   
                $data = array();
                $data["relationTo"] = $rel["name"];
                $data["relation"] = $rel["relation"];
        $this->children[] = new Child($id, $rel["sname"],$data);
            }
            else {
                $this->id = $id+1;
                $this->name = $sname;
                $this->data = $data;
            }
        }       
    }
    $childrel = array();
    $id = 0;
    foreach($relations as $rel){
        $childrel[] = new Child($id ,"","", $rel);
        $id = $id + 1;
    }
```

Comment: do a `json_decode` in the 1st string. then reverse engineer it. you'l get the array format then and make the new arrays accordingly.

Comment: In posted code you never assign `$children[$id]["children"]`, so it should not appear in the json at all (it is there as empty array). Post all your code which manipulates `$children` array.

Comment: I added an edit of another attempt at this through creating a class ... with my other code I was just starting with a new attempt I am not sure how I would show more $children that are within other $children... @itachi I am trying the json_decode so far I can't seem to get this function working but ill keep working on it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared $children before assigning values to it before foreach loop. Hence declare the array like this and alter the code to this

```
$children = array();
$id = 0;
    foreach($relations as $rel){
        $children[$id]["id"] = $id+1;
        $children[$id]["name"] = $rel["sname"];
        $children[$id]["data"] = $data[$id];
        $id = $id + 1;
    }
```

Comment: I actually declared sorry I did not include that in the code above but I showed the output that I was getting and I am able to input children into the first created id/name but I wasn't able to get children of the next set of children and so on...